# If $x_{n+1}\geq\frac{x_n}{2}>0$ and $\sum x_n=l,$ then for every $0<c\leq l,$ is there a subsequence of $(x_n)$ whose sum is $c?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Motivation: If $\ x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2} > 0\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ then for every $\ 0<c\leq l:=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n,\ $ there is a subsequence
$\ \left(x_{k_n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ of $\ \left( x_n \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ such that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{k_n} = c.\ $ This can be seen by, for example, looking at the binary expansion of $\frac{l}{c},$ or (closely related), by writing $\frac{l}{c}$ as the nested intersection of intervals of size $2^{-n}.$

Question:

> If $\ x_{n+1} \geq \frac{x_n}{2} > 0\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ and
> $\ \displaystyle\sum_{ n=1}^{\infty} x_n = l\in\mathbb{R},\ $ then for
> every $\ 0<c\leq l,\ $ is  there a subsequence $\ \left( x_{k_n}
>  \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ of $\ \left( x_n \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\
>  $ such that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{k_n} = c.\ ?$

I fail at finding a counter-example, or a good proof strategy for the affirmative.

Comment: The motivation sequence is just $2^{-n}$ times a positive constant. My question says $\ x_{n+1} \geq \frac{x_n}{2} > 0\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ which allows for sequences like $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0.7, x_3 = 0.5, x_4 = 0.6, x_5 = 0.3, ...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x_{n} \le \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty x_k$. You can use a "greedy" approach:
having decided on whether to include $x_j$ for $j < k$, and needing to make
the sum $t$ using $x_k, x_{k+1}, \ldots$ where $\sum_{j=k}^\infty x_j \ge t$, include
$x_k$ if $x_k \le t$ but don't include it if $x_k > t$.

Comment: Right. If you do include $x_k$ but not $x_{k-1}$ because $x_{k-1}$ was too large to include, then including $x_k$ in the sum will get you at least half of the way closer to the sum. So the greedy algorithm does converge to the sum.